# Adding custom Email button

Tags: email, attachment

I am displaying an image (saved in Static resource) on a click of button on Lead's detail page. I need to add a button to send an email which automatically attaches this image and should have Lead's name/email ID in "To" (just like the default Salesforce's "Send an Email" button), which I think can be done by Email Template. But how can we open the template with already attached Image. Kindly suggest.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameters to the standard salesforce email page for this - see [here](http://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/url-hack-revisted-auto-select-email-template-with-custom-button/).
Then in your E-Mail Template you can specify which fields to use and they will be pre-filled automatically.